# How to avoid unexpected values in border of slope raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, slope

I have a DEM like

[image: DEM]

After calculating slope with QGIS, it's showing the following result

[image: slope]

So, how can I remove the unexpected value at the edge of this DEM? *Which is showing almost 90 degree values.*

Comment: What is the exact command you executed - especially regarding the option to "compute edges"?

Comment: By reading the documentation http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html the edges should be dealt rather well if the area outside the real DEM data is marked as NoData. What does gdalinfo report about your DEM image? If the offsite area is not NoData but just a constant value like "0" it is natural that a computer finds very steep slopes.

Comment: With experience you learn to clip all your raster data initially to a region that equals your study area *expanded by several cells.*  After various focal operations, like slope calculation, are carried out, you will predictably lose a thin border of data to such "edge effects"--but that border will still lie outside your study area, at least if you make the buffer sufficiently large.  Then, after all data processing is done, you can clip your results to the study area and will have no problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your DEM to a vector polygon with menu Raster > Conversion > Polygonize. Then clip the slope grid to the polygonized vector DEM. Clip the raster with menu Raster > Extracting > Clipper...

I am not aware of any setting your can set to avoid the extra pixels when creating a slope.

More on raster clipping here: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html